# Bootstrap CSS background image not working in Yii Application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have tried to insert image background
[image]

How the code should be written? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your image line like below

```
background-image: url('/images/bg2.jpg');
```

Please be make sure that your given URL is correct path for the Image.

Comment: still not working. yeah I have checked the path, this where I put the image C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\asus\images\bg2.jpg but still not working

Comment: I think it should be a problem on your path.. First host image in http://postimage.org/ & give that URL to it..if this working then you must check your URL